# Не выделяется активная страница навигационного меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Всем привет! У меня проблемка: не выделяется активная страница навигационного меню - не понимаю в чем ошибка..

```js
$('.nav.navbar-nav li a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]').parent().addClass('activenav');
```

```css
 .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
   opacity: 0;
   -moz-transition: all 800ms ease;
   -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease;
   -o-transition: all 800ms ease;
   -ms-transition: all 800ms ease;
   transition: all 800ms ease;
 }
 .dropdown-menu>li>a {
   padding: 8px 20px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
 .dropdown-menu>.last>a {
   border: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="../index.php">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>


        <li>
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>

        <li class="last">
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <!-- end dropdown-menu -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Не плодите вопросы. Уже третий вопрос с этим куском кода.

Comment: Создайте еще один вопрос, может поумнеете...